# hide div in a certain html page

Tags: php, html, css

apology for this newbie question.

I have created an html page (dash.html) that uses the same `header` as the other pages.
it calls this PHP function `<?php include 'header.php'; ?>`

the dash.html contains a special `<div>` made specially for that page; and it must be placed inside the `header.php`

im trying to figure out how to enable/disable a certain `div` on a certain html page.

will it require a PHP conditional statement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. The easiest way is to include a conditional line in the header, and pass the checked variable from each page that calls header. So, in your dash.php (it can't be a .html if it calls php, can it?):

```
<?php
    $includediv = true; // set to false, or leave out, if you don't want the div
    include('header.php');
?>
```

and in the header.php:

```
<?php
...some other code...
if($includediv){
    ...code to include div...
}
?>
```

This will continue to work as before for all other pages that call header.php.

Comment: lovely! thanks for this. i just added  `echo '<div id="test">  hello</div>';` after the conditional statement and it worked! :)

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to show the `div` only if `header.php` is present, right?

So, just set a variable inside `header.php` and use a conditional inside the HTML page.

Answer (score 0):

```
Try this code

<?php 
$path=explode('/',$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
$page=end($path);
if($page=='dash.php')
{
?>
<div>your div for dash.php page</div>
<?php } ?>
```